# Prompted for credentials when using a shared data source with Report Builder 2.0 over the Internet with forms authentication

Tags: forms-authentication, ssrs-2008, report-builder2.0

SQL Server 2008 (not R2). I am trying to allow users to build and deploy SSRS reports on a reporting server that the users can only access over the Internet. I have created a custom forms authentication provider.

I can now connect to the reporting server over the Internet via either the report manager or report builder 2.0. What I would like to do is to provide the user with a shared data source which he/she can use in reports. I have created a data source with credentials stored on the server. Now, I can create a report and add the shared data source. However, when I try to add a data set, I get prompted for credentials for the data source. If I have access to the database server over the network, I can put in the credentials and everything works. However, when working over the Internet (the db server is not accessible from outside the firewall) it fails with "Login failed for ".

I think it's trying to connect directly to the database server when I do this rather than connecting through the report server and using the shared data source. If I use a shared model on the server instead of a data source, it works fine, but I'd like the flexibility of using a data source.

Is this possible? If not, does anyone know if it's different in R2/RB3? I don't have access to R2 to test.

Thanks in advance,

Josh

Comment: You didn't get any responses but did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Peter, what I basically figured out is that when you go to add or change a dataset and report builder needs to get a list of tables/fields from the data source, it connects directly instead of through the report server. Microsoft does this out of security concerns (they don't want to send the credentials for the data source from the report server back to report builder). However, it seems like they should just have report builder request the information it needs from the reporting server and have that query the DB and send the meta-data back.

Comment: I suffer from this a lot with my subscription-based reports which require a secure set of credentials in order for the subscription to run.
If i don't switch back to the generic DB connection before trying to edit/add a new datasource I am always prompted for credentials and no account seems to be able to satisfy the prompt! Very irritating!